# java wsimport rename/different ObjectFactory.java

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport, objectfactory

I'm having problem with `wsimport`. In one of my wsdl which has to be `wsimport`ed I have a complexType with name `"objectFactory"`. Is there any way to tell command `wsimport` to create while importing different class for maintaining JAXB connections such is `ObjectFactory.java`. In other words can I tell `wsimport` instead of creating `ObjectFactory.java` some custom class like `MyCustomFactory.java`?

Is it possible to customize mapping in such a way that `complexType name="objectFactory"` would map to object with different name like `MyObjectFactory.java`?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

JAX-WS (of which `wsimport` is a part) uses JAXB for generating the XML binding files (and for doing the actual binding). So you'll want to check out [this documentation on customizing JAXB bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html). It applies just as well to your case.

In your case you'd use something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="objectFactory">
  <xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:appinfo>
     <jxb:class name="MyObjectFactory" />
  </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <!-- ... rest of your specification ... ->
</xsd:complexType>
```

This example is for inline customization in your XML Schema/WSDL. You can also provide this information as [external configuration](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html#bnbbi).

Comment: If I understand this right I need to change WSDL file and insert above sample into WSDL file? Or can I create external binding file to transform it to proper class? Example pls

Comment: Changing the WSDL is **one** way. Examples for specifying external configuration are found in the documentation I linked to.